# FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in PermissionRegistrar.php

Tags: php, laravel

When I reinstall my xampp and run my laravel project ,I'm getting this error
FatalErrorException

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in
>   PermissionRegistrar.php (line 33)
>   My code is

```
public function __construct(Gate $gate, Repository $cache, Log $logger)
{
    $this->gate = $gate;
    $this->cache = $cache;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
public function registerPermissions(): bool
{
    try {
        $this->getPermissions()->map(function (Permission $permission) {
    $this->gate->define($permission->name, function ($user) use($permission) 
{
                return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission);
            });
        });
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        if ($this->shouldLogException()) {
            $this->logger->alert(
 "Could not register permissions because {$exceptiongetMessage()}".PHP_EOL.
                $exception->getTraceAsString()
            );
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? The error is clear. Why don't you fix it?

Comment: @saranya : 1) Please check your loop is close correctly or not. 2) please verify any semiclon is missing

Comment: share `PermissionRegistrar.php (line 33)` and one line above ?

Comment: I 've updated my code

Comment: which PHP version  you are using?

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.31

Comment: remove `: bool`

Answer (score 0):

[Return type declaration support is added to php 7](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration). So remove `: bool` (as you are currently on PHP 5.6.31) from

```
public function registerPermissions(): bool
```

to

```
public function registerPermissions()
```

Comment: I guess this is a php version problem Isn't it?

Comment: yes, its PHP version issue, that's why I asked you your current version. Syntax you have used is supported by PHP 7

Comment: Glad to help you :) You can accept as answer if found useful